# Why does discrete data distribution has differential entropy of negative infinity?

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy, information-theory

Recently I've been reading “[A note on the evaluation of generative models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.01844.pdf)” by Lucas Theis, Aäron van den Oord, Matthias Bethge.
In section 3.1, it says "Since the discrete data distribution has differential entropy of negative infinity, this can lead to arbitrary high likelihoods even on test data."

I don't understand why could differential entropy be 'negative infinity', and why can it cause 'high likelihood'.

Can someone help me?

Comment: it's probably an unfortunate language: it can be negative for discrete distributions but doesn't have to be negative infinity

Comment: @Aksakal The paper refers explicitly to the differential entropy between some underlying *continuous* distribution and a discrete distribution: "an image is treated as an instance of a continuous random variable."

Comment: @whuber maybe "the" refers to a particular distribution, but the language appears to suggest a general statement about the discrete distributions. also, i think the paper refers to a *differential entropy* extension of shannon's discrete entropy, not the difference between distributions as it's evident from Eq(3)

Comment: @Aksakal.  Right: and isn't it the case that in that sense all continuous distributions are infinitely far from all non-continuous distributions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The differential entropy is defined as:
$$h=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ln(f(x))dx$$
vwhere $f(x)$ is the PDf of the function. For the discrete distribution, there is not PDF, but there is a probability mass function. However, we could represent the PDF with Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$:
$$f(x)=\sum_ip_i\delta(x-x_i)$$
where $p_i$ is the probability of outcome $x_i$.
For instance, Benroulli distribution psudo PDF would be: $$f(x)=\frac{\delta(x)+\delta(x-1)}{2}$$

You can see that this sort of behaves like PDF:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=\sum_ip_i\equiv 1$$ etc.

Now, if you plug this PDF like creature into the differential entropy you get the following:
$$\begin{align}
h&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ln(f(x))dx \\
&=
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\sum_ip_i\delta(x-x_i)\right)\ln\left(\sum_kp_k\delta(x-x_k)\right)dx \\
&=
-\sum_ip_i\ln\left(\sum_kp_k\delta(x_i-x_k)\right) \\
&=-\infty
\end{align}$$
You can see why this doesn't converge: for any $k= i$ you get $\delta(0)$, which can be interpreted as infinity.

Hence, the conclusion that differential entropy for discrete distributions is negative infinity. However, you should not be normally dealing with this, because for discrete distribution you would usually apply a conventional entropy formula : $h=-\sum_i p_i\ln p_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm curious about how we can represent the PDF as a sum of Dirac delta's? Do you perhaps have a source or further explanation? Thank you!

Comment: @ChristabellaIrwanto, Bernoulli distribution PDF is $f(x)=\frac 1 2\delta(0)+\frac 1 2\delta(1)$. CDF is $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(s)ds$ so $F(0)=0,F(0+)=1/2,F(1)=1/2,F(1+)=1$

Comment: @Aksakal probably stupid question - but why do we have to sum over `i` in first term and over `k` in the second part? Why don't we sum just over `i`?

Comment: @PavelPodlipensky consider this:$f=a+b$ then $f\ln f=(a+b)\ln(a+b)=a\ln(a+b)+b\ln(a+b)$ not $a\ln a+b\ln b$, it's the same idea.

Comment: @Aksakal thank you for such a nice explanation! Actually I'm working on uncertainty estimation for VAE and questions like the one in this thread do arise a lot. And I would love some help. Please ping me at my twitter account https://twitter.com/podlipensky if you're interested in collaboration/work?

Answer (score 2):

The next sentence in that paper has a citation that clears it up:

> To avoid this case, it is becoming best practice to add real-valued noise
> to the integer pixel values to dequantize the data (e.g., Uria et al., 2013; van den Oord & Schrauwen, 2014; Theis & Bethge, 2015))

The [Uria et al. 2013 paper on RNADE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0186.pdf) explains it well:

> Pixels in this dataset can take a finite number of brightness values ranging from 0 to 255. Modeling discretized data using a real-valued distribution can lead to arbitrarily high density values, by locating
> narrow high density spike on each of the possible discrete values. In order to avoid this "cheating" solution, we added noise uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 to the value of each pixel.